# how to plot time points in a day on excel

Tags: excel

I have a set of points as time of day like

```
05:36:37
06:31:41
06:38:24
06:39:42
07:03:47
07:04:18
07:09:28
07:28:40
07:29:20
07:29:49
07:31:57
.....
```

Now i would like to plot this for an entire 24 hour range in a day.

Basically x axis is the 24 hour range and i need a point for every above time on the y axis. ofcourse y axis may not vary, but i am loooking at finding the coverage as to, in a day, when did the even occur more times. Its the same event. If there are better ways to represent you can also suggest that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data is from `A1` to `A_N`.

in column B enter `=HOUR(A1)`
in column C enter `=MINUTE(A1)`

Then `Insert` -> `XY Scatter Chart`

[image]

Comment: When i write =HOUR(A1) I just get 00:00:00 as the cell value. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: check the number format e.g. `h:mm:ss`, looks buggy same happened now to me with the minutes.

Comment: A reliable solution is to import those times as `:` delimited fields, and import the times into three columns.